# Extracting numbers preceded by words from a txt. file in python

Tags: python, file, extract

I am trying to extract specific numbers from a seperate file after the name of a country. The code does not seem to show any input and I have almost no clue what I am doing.

It shows output but only the else where it says either No life Expectancy data or No Gini Data.

Here is an example of the file I am extracting from

```
1:      Lesotho                                            :63.2                                              

2:      South Africa                                       :62.5                                              

3:      Central African Republic                           :61.3                                              

4:      Micronesia, Federated States of                    :61.1                                              

5:      Haiti                                              :60.8
```

and here is the code I have so far

```
country = []
info = [] 
def countryFinder(fileName,info):

    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    line = infile.readline()

    for line in infile:
        fields = line.split(":")
        country.append(fields[1].strip())
        info.append(fields[2].strip())

        return country, info

userCountry = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")

life = countryFinder("life.txt",info)
gini = countryFinder("gini.txt",info)



while userCountry != "q":
    if userCountry in life:
        print ("  Life Expectancy is ",life[info]," years at birth")
    else:
        print ("  No Life Expectancy Data")

    if userCountry in gini:
        print ("  Gini Value is ",gini[info])
    else:
        print ("  No Gini Data")

    userCountry = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")
```

Software: spyder with python 3.6

Comment: Do you mean code doesn't show any output? Also, 1) Indicate which version of python you are using 2) Does this script compile or are you getting error messages?

Comment: Have you checked the values held in your variables and different points in the code to verify values are as you expected? You could set some test assert cases.

Comment: For example, should country in your function actually be country = fields[1] ?

Comment: @QHarr it shows output but only the else where it  says either No life Expectancy data or No Gini Data

Comment: and I am using spyder with python 3.6

Comment: Did you check your search values? E.g. country

Comment: Yes, I moved them forward one and that helped however the definition does not seem to work for the second part to change the original list to where it works  for the if else statements.

Comment: I know i keep asking but have you taken a test case and put it through your code? Compare the expected values at each stage with the actual? You could use assert statements for this. Checking that your lists contain the values you expect and have been added to correctly for example.

Comment: I checked for that definition(which worked) however I am not entirely sure how on the rest, but I think it does not work outside of the definition

Comment: How is your function returning?

Comment: no life expectancy data                                                                                                no gini data

Comment: and then it loops back to the start and asks again as intended

Comment: I meant how are you returning values from your country finder function? It has been a while since i have done any python but should there be a return statement to your function?

Comment: oh that would make sense I'm not quite sure how to do that though. I'm in the process of learning python and do not know very much.

Comment: Why there are two text files: life.txt and gini.txt? Are they the same?

Comment: no two different files same sort of data though

Comment: Decide how you want to return values as this will determine how you later access them e.g. you could add the line return country, info

Comment: And you are passing lists so you want to append to them e.g.  country.append(fields[0])
    info.append(fields[1])

Comment: Ok, that helped and I changed the code around however I still do not recieve a true for a country being in a file

Comment: place = []
info = [] 
def countryFinder(fileName,info):
    
    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    line = infile.readline()

    for line in infile:
        line.strip()
        fields = line.split(":")
        place.append(fields[1])
        info.append(fields[2])
        
        

country = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")

life = countryFinder("life.txt",info)
gini = countryFinder("gini.txt",info)

Comment: while country != "q":
    if country in life:
        print ("  Life Expectancy is ",life[info]," years at birth")
    else:
        print ("  No Life Expectancy Data")
        
    if country in gini:
        print ("  Gini Value is ",gini[info])
    else:
        print ("  No Gini Data")
        
    country = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")

Comment: is there a better way to post code because that is what I currently have.

Comment: Should I just edit the original code?

Comment: yes you should always edit additional info and revised code back into the question. Makes it easier for people to find. Others can search through the revision history if necessary.

Comment: Have deleted my answer as more useful answer given.

Comment: @QHarr: you shouldn't have :D

Comment: @user2978216 I haven't written python in a while and your code looked like a more immediate and complete solution (bascially better!). I didn't want to confuse the OP. Does mean i should probaby do some python practice :-)

Comment: @QHarr: nooo it's not better. But I had fun trying to make the code work without making big changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wrote a good code just missed some lines here and there. I've marked lines that you've missed with #

```
country = []
info = []
dic = {} #
def countryFinder(fileName,info):

    infile = open(fileName, "r")
    line = infile.readline()

    infile = open(fileName, "r").readlines() #

    for line in infile:
        line.strip()
        fields = line.split(":")
        fields = fields[1:3] #
        country = fields[0]
        country = country.strip() #
        info = fields[1]
        info = float(info.strip("\n")) #
        dic[country] = info #
    return dic.copy() #

country = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")
life = countryFinder("life.txt",info)
gini = countryFinder("gini.txt",info)

while country != "q":
    info = life #
    if country in info:
        info = country #
        print ("  Life Expectancy is ",life[info]," years at birth")
    else:
        print ("  No Life Expectancy Data")

    info = gini #
    if country in info:
        info = country #
        print ("  Gini Value is ",gini[info])
    else:
        print ("  No Gini Data")

    country = input("Please enter a country (\"q to quit\"): ")
```

Comment: this does not seem to work it is bringing up "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' "

Comment: Please provide life.txt and gini.txt files and I take a look

Comment: how can you linnk a file?

Comment: @Rad_Dad: I've updated the solution. Let me know if it works now.

Comment: @Rad_Dad you are welcome! :) Please don't forget to mark the answer as the solution